# Does second countablity implies closed (or open) set in $X$ is a countable intersection of open sets in $X$?

Tags: general-topology, second-countable

Is $X$ is second countable implies or equivalent to Every closed(or open) set in $X$ is a countable intersection of open sets in $X$?

---

I know, metric space implies this by [Closed set as a countable intersection of open sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504798/closed-set-as-a-countable-intersection-of-open-sets), and [Every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of closed sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444562/every-open-set-in-mathbbr-is-a-countable-union-of-closed-sets).  Also I know metric space is 1st countable but not 2nd countable.

If so How one can prove this statement?

Comment: In any metric space any closed set is a  countable intersection of open sets. A metric space need not be second countable. So equivalence of these two is not true.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy, yes I know metric space satisfies the above property. I wonder whether a similar thing holds for 2nd countable case or need to impose a further topological condition, such as normal.

Comment: You definitely need something more, e.g., $X$ has at least 2 points, with only 3 open sets.  Then the nontrivial closed set $F\subset X$ is not an intersection of opens.

Comment: i.e., Since $X$ regular+second countable implies $X$ is metrizable and separable, normal+second countable space is metric space, so for this case the above holds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The natural numbers $\ge 2$ endowed with the topology of the subsets that contain the divisors of each of their elements is second-countable, but not $G_\delta$.

Comment: Off-topic: Your answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4213665/) still seems correct to me: Even though the series converges to an $L^2$ function a.e. according to WolframAlpha, there is no $L^2$ function with that series as its Fourier series.

Answer (score 0):

The Double Arrow space ($[0,1] \times \{0,1\}$ in the order topology induced from the lexicographer order) is **not** second countable but is compact, connected and every closed subset is a countable intersection of open sets (it’s perfectly normal). So it’s **not** equivalent.

Comment: BTW even for metric spaces $\Bbb R$ in the discrete metric is already a counterexample.